# Regex to match any number of repititions except k

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all text which doesn't match the following pattern `^([^\.]*\.){3}[^\.]*$` - i.e. any text seperated by 3 periods (.) for example XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX does match,  XX.XX or XX.XX.XX.XX.XX does not.

Any character except the period can be used in place of X, i.e. I want essentially want to count the number of periods in the string and filter by the count <> 3 (the expression above does the opposite, i.e. matches when the count == 3)

How do you say match 1,2 or 4+ times?

Comment: Can you give a couple more examples of strings that should / should not match please. What characters are allowed to go where you have `X`?

Comment: X can be anything other than .

Comment: Could the string be `XX.X.XX` or is it known that the number of X's is the same per group; i.e., it is only the number per group that is not known? Can the string be `AB.CD.EF` or must all characters in the string other than the periods (the X's) be the same character? If the latter, is that character known?

Comment: The number of X's per group varies (any number) and can be any character (other than the deliminter itself). Basically I have delimited data and I'm trying to find malformed lines - I'm using Google OpenRefine hence the use of Regex rather than simply count the delimiters. So think of it as CSV data (but with . as the deliminter) with some records having the "wrong" number of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Negative Lookahead with what you don't want and if the condition satisfied capture anything:

The general idea:

```
(?!^not_this_pattern$)^[\s\S]*$
```

`[\s\S]` capture anything, including new line (in contrast to `.`)

And for this example:

```
(?!^([^\.]*\.){3}[^\.]*$)^[\s\S]*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1NBua/1)**

Or alternatively use condition operator `|` for the pattern to repeat (2 or less) or (4 or more):

```
^((?:[^\.]*\.[^\.]*){,2}|(?:[^\.]*\.[^\.]*){4,})$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EowlZD/1)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to simplify your question down to the core piece: how to match any number of repetitions except `k`.  To that end, I'll simplify the expression down to `x`.  After all, this should work with any expression, so might as well start off simple.

Regex provides two useful constructs for us:

1. The "n or more" construct `{n,}`

   - This specifies that you want this expression to repeat `n` or more times.
2. The "range" construct `{n,m}`

   - This specifies that you want this expression to repeat any number of times between `n` and `m`, inclusive.

We can put these together using regex's OR notation (`|`) to match "between 1 and `k - 1` times" (`{1,k-1}`) and "`k + 1` or more times" (`{k+1,}`), separately.  We are using `k - 1` and `k + 1` as bounds because both of these functions are inclusive, and we want to exclude `k`.  If we wanted `k` to be, say, 3, we would end up with the following expression:

```
^(x{1,2}|x{4,})$
```

Now, this could be a problem if you happen to have a really long expression, since you would have to type the expression out twice.  This could get really long!  Luckily, we can refer back to a capturing group we made earlier.  The syntax is `(?n)`, where `n` denotes which capturing group you are referring to.  In this case, we'll put our pattern in the first capturing group, and we'll refer to it using `(?1)`.  This gives us:

```
^(x)((?1){0,1}|(?1){3,})$
```

Notice that I used 0 to 1 and 3+ as my quantifiers because we already matched the expression once at the beginning of our pattern.  One caveat here is that not all flavors of regex support this syntax.  PCRE (and PCRE2) supports it, but Python, Golang, Java, and ECMAScript do not.

Now all we've got left is to plug in your pattern.  Super easy, we can just drop it in where `x` is in our previous patterns:

Using the first method, if you aren't using PCRE or you have a short expression:

```
^(([^\.]*\.){1,2}|([^\.]*\.){4,})[^\.]*$
```

And using the second method, if you're using PCRE and you have a long expression:

```
^([^\.]*\.)((?1){0,1}|(?1){3,})[^\.]*$
```